# SXA with Preprocessors?

Tags: sxa

For creative exchange exports and imports, is it possible to use a pre-processor such as sass or less?  Is exporting and importing css files the only option?

Comment: I've been curious about how, if possible, to setup a pipeline to perform the transpiling of SASS and TypeScript as a step before the Asset Optimizer minifies. Maybe Alan or Dawid know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment Creative Exchange is only working with CSS files. You can create separate folder inside of your theme (on the same level as Scripts and Styles folders) called for example Sass. 
Then content of that folder should be exported too by Creative Exchange.

**But** - SASS/LESS files won't be processed.

Regarding Michael West question: It will be possible in next version of Creative Exchange which is coming soon. Next version will bring lot of new pipelines in different parts of export and import process. Full control and lot of customization possibilities! So it will be easy to implement that.